# panic: runtime error: index out of range in Go

Tags: go

I have the following function that takes a command from terminal and prints something based on input. It seems simple enough, if the user types 'add' the system prints a line, if the user types nothing, it prints something else.

Whenever the user types add, it works. If the user doesn't type anything it throws

panic: runtime error: index out of range in GoLang

Why is this?

```
  func bootstrapCmd(c *commander.Command, inp []string) error {


     if inp[0] == "add" {
                  fmt.Println("you typed add")
              } else if inp[0] == "" {
                  fmt.Println("you didn't type add")
              }


          return nil

    }
```

Comment: This is the kind of exception you'll encounter your whole life! After the 100+ time though, you'll develop a 6th sense for it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If the user does not provide any input, the `inp` array is empty. This means that even the index `0` is out of range, i.e. `inp[0]` can't be accessed.

You can check the length of `inp` with `len(inp)` before checking `inp[0] == "add"`. Something like this might do:

```
if len(inp) == 0 {
    fmt.Println("you didn't type add")
} else if inp[0] == "add" {
    fmt.Println("you typed add")
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You have to check the length of `inp` first:

```
func bootstrapCmd(c *commander.Command, inp []string) (err error) {
    if len(inp) == 0 {
        return errors.New("no input")
    }
    switch inp[0] {
    case "add":
        fmt.Println("you typed add")
    case "sub":
        fmt.Println("you typed sub")
    default:
        fmt.Println("invalid:", inp[0])
    }
    return nil

}
```

Answer (score -7):

Also you can use `recover()` for check existing index of slices

```
func takes(s []string, i int) string {
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
           return
        }
    }()
    return s[i]
}

if takes(inp,0) == "add" {
   fmt.Println("you typed add")
} else {
   fmt.Println("you didn't type add")
}
```

Comment: This is a terrible terrible advice, please never do that, ever.

Comment: @OneOfOne could you explain why it's bad?

Comment: @PieceDigital 1. it's expensive and slow. 2. it encourages extremely bad programming practices that shouldn't be used, you can easily check `if i < len(s) { return s[i] } return ""`.

Comment: Let's say you're parsing a binary format that 99.9999% of the is given correct lengths by the remote, but occasionally a malicious packet is sent. Would it be better to always do a dozen length checks? or to handle the 0.00001% case with a recover()?

Comment: I'm not so sure that catching a panic is particularly more expensive than returning an error: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2018/on-the-uses-and-misuses-of-panics-in-go/

I get that in the one-off case mentioned by the OP that panicking would be a poor choice, but in the case of a parsers it appears that it is the preferred way to handle this sort of situation.