# How on the place of empty space in the csv file the empty string value is added in database

Tags: go, import-csv

My csv file having user data like this:

```
 firstname|lastname|Email| other fields are empty
          |        |     |
          |        |     |
          |        |     |
          |        |     |
```

The code I'm using is:

```
 package main

import (
 "encoding/csv"
 "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
 "io"
 "log"
 "os"
)

type Mongo struct {
  // Id          int    `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
  FirstName   string `json:"first_name,omitempty" bson:"first_name,omitempty"`
  LastName    string `json:"last_name,omitempty" bson:"last_name,omitempty"`
  Email       string `json:"email,omitempty" bson:"email,omitempty"`
  PhoneNumber string `json:"phone_number,omitempty" bson:"phone_number,omitempty"`
  Gender      string `json:"gender,omitempty" bson:"gender,omitempty"`
  Address     string `json:"address,omitempty" bson:"address,omitempty"`
  Apartment   string `json:"apartment,omitempty" bson:"apartment,omitempty"`
  Description string `json:"description,omitempty" bson:"description,omitempty"`
 }

func main() {

 session, err := mgo.Dial("localhost")
 if err != nil {
    panic(err)
 }

 defer session.Close()
 session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

 c := session.DB("Import_Users").C("users")

 file, err := os.Open("customers.csv")

 if err != nil {
    panic(err)
 }
 defer file.Close()

 reader := csv.NewReader(file)

 for {
    record, err := reader.Read()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = c.Insert(&Mongo{record[0], record[1], record[2], record[3], record[4], record[5], record[6], record[7]})

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Printf("%#v", record)
 }
}
```

The error is coming while running:

> Error:-
>   panic: runtime error: index out of range
>
> goroutine 1 [running]:
>   main.main()
>     /home/iron/go/src/go-training/How_to_load_csv_file/main.go:53 +0x830
>   exit status 2

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [panic: runtime error: index out of range in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126235/panic-runtime-error-index-out-of-range-in-go)

Comment: @Capricorn I don't get how I will write it in my code can you please explain it

Comment: Try to print number of records before inserting to mongo, and then provide the index of `record` slice. As I can see there can be only one mistake in your code and that is you are providing an index to `record` slice which does not exists.

Comment: `record` doesn't have 8 elements in it, it's length will match the number of columns in the csv row. So indexing outside of the `record`'s range results in a runtime error. A quick fix would be to do `row := make([]string, 8); copy(row, record)` and then use `row` to construct `Mongo`.

Comment: @Himanshu can you tell me where the error is

Comment: @Himanshu as you say i will print the records see in discussion

Comment: `[Michaelhycle Michaelhycle yrf45@mail4you.racing asd]` //records
`<nil>` //err
`panic: runtime error: index out of range`

`goroutine 1 [running]:`
`main.main()`
 `/home/iron/go/src/go-training/How_to_load_csv_file/main.go:55 +0x90d`

Comment: @mkopriva can you provide me a example of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have slice elements for `record[0]` through `record[7]`. Add empty padding elements. For example,

```
reader := csv.NewReader(file)
padding := make([]string, 8)  // 0 thru 7
for {
    record, err := reader.Read()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    record = append(record, padding...)
    err = c.Insert(&Mongo{record[0], record[1], record[2], record[3], record[4], record[5], record[6], record[7]})

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Printf("%#v", record)
}
```

Comment: it is alright for now but if the user want to add new field in it then it will take `7` more then for this how will we do.

Comment: if user will create a new field in csv file then we have to change this `padding := make([]string, 8) ` to `9`. I'm right?

Comment: @ansh: The length of the padding allocation should be one more that the maximum element index referenced, In this case, `record[7]`, `8 = 7 + 1`. If you add `record[8]`, allocate `9 = 8 + 1`.

Comment: one more thing if the field is empty then it will not save into the database, right?

Comment: @ansh: You have `omitempty` for the `Mongo` `struct` fields which should omit any empty fields on a write.

Comment: okay @peterSO for this answer and thanks for giving me your golden time for solving my question. :p

Comment: @ansh: "The "omitempty" option specifies that the field should be omitted from the encoding if the field has an empty value, defined as false, 0, a nil pointer, a nil interface value, and any empty array, slice, map, or string."

Comment: okay once again thanks @peterSO I'm new on go so thats why little bit difficult for me